# Can using isopropyl alcohol on a zirconium oxide ceramic knife harm or dissolve/degrade it?

Tags: solubility, ceramics

Can using isopropyl alcohol to clean a zirconium oxide ceramic knife harm or dissolve/degrade it?

Comment: It wouldn't harm the ceramic blade, but it might not be good for the handle. **SAFETY -- Isopropyl alcohol also isn't safe for consumption. So that seems like a poor choice to be used around food.**

Comment: Ethyl alcohol (i.e. everclear > 90%  alcohol) would be safer with respect to @MaxW 's comment, and also would not harm the knife.  Still, I'd guess that soap and water with a good sponge would work as well as anything, unless it's been used for something odd outside of cooking.  With any of the solutions discussed I think the biggest danger is just how slippery it's going to be, especially if you are scrubbing hard.  That can easily put you on the fast track to the emergency room!  Good luck with it...

Comment: Zirconium dioxide or zirconia is chemically unreactive. It only dissolves in hydrofluoric acid and sulfuric acid.

Comment: thank you very much everyone, I 'm actually also using scissors for hair and just wanted to make sure it wouldn't dissolve the zirconium oxide that it says it's made out of and then get onto my skin and harm me some way.  I will use the isopropyl alcohol just as a final rinse after washing the blades.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  of low quality

Comment: @A.K. If the lower quality of the post has a specific reason (being too broad/opinion-based/homework-ish/etc.), you should use _that_ particular close reason for the post. Otherwise, I don't think a "low-quality" custom close vote is justifiable. You should rather downvote the post instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zirconium dioxide is not soluble in organic solvents like isopropyl alcohol. Of more concern would be any plastic component of the knife, like a handle that could be damaged by isopropyl alcohol or other solvents.

Comment: True...I do not know what kind of plastic the handles are made out of.  But isopropyl alcohol is usually sold in plastic containers, most likely LDPE, HDPE, or PP.  So if the handle is made of one of those plastics, it should be safe?

Comment: I was being pretty cautious with that statement, and it's pretty unlikely that isopropanol will attack any plastics on the knife. Acetone would be a much greater risk for example. If you want to play it safe, maybe try a spot-test with a little isopropanol on an inconspicuous part of the plastic. If there is no change in appearance or texture after it dries then you should be safe.